# Best way to handle circular dependencies in production

Tags: sql, dependencies, constraints, relationship, erd

What is the common practice or best way to handle circular dependencies in a newly deployed database?

Let's say I have a new database ready to be deployed in production. What is the best way or common practice to handle circular dependencies? Here are the options I could think of:

[image: [world erd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwr7y.png)]

1. Temporarily turn off constraints
2. Create a schema that has less dependencies to other entities by creating an additional table e.g. using the SQL world context (Continent, country, capital, city) entities, I would remove the foreign key capital_id from the Country entity and create a new table country_capital which attributes are:
   `CREATE TABLE country_capital ( country_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, capital_id INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES country (country_id), FOREIGN KEY (capital_id) REFERENCES capital (capital_id) );`

Please give advice. Thanks

I didn't try anything, I just want to know the best way to handle circular dependencies.

Comment: I’d probably design the data model correctly so that it doesn’t have circular dependencies

Answer (score 0):

#### What about your two alternatives?

Circular dependencies are not a problem but a solution to many real-life needs.  he issue here is the circular dependency combined with the minimal cardinality of 1:

- The solution 1 is not a real solution, because every time you turn off the constraint, it might be infringed, so why set it in the first place?  Moreover, what would you do if reactivating the constraint would fail?
- The solution 2 is a better approach.  You do not need to remove the relationships nor the constraints, but to relax the cardinality by going from 1:1 to 0:1.

  So avoid the `NOT NULL` on foreign key columns in such cases. In my own experience, this is a proven, pragmatic solution that also deals very well with exceptional cases where are relationship may exist but is not known at some times.

#### A better solution to address other consistency issues?

Another issue is that the model allows to have a country with a capital that is the capital of another country.  This is not a general issue with the circular dependencies, but a problem with the specific semantics that you attach to this relationship where you expect reciprocity.

The best approach in this case is to **implement the relationship with an associative table**: The country table would not have a capital column.  The capital would not have a country column. Instead, you'd create a table `country_capital` containing a foreign key to the country, a foreign key to the capital, a composite primary key containing both ids,  and a UNIQUE constraint on each of its columns.

[image]

#### What about the big picture?

Now that we have a more consistent model,  we can also remind that a capital is a city and has a population too.  You could therefore reengineer the model:

- option 1) make capital an associative entity between country and city
- option 2) or instead, make capital a boolean attribute of city (to avoid inconsistencies between country columns).